# Redshift drop/create/select query failing in Data Pipeline

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, amazon-data-pipeline

I'm trying to run a daily migration script in Redshift using Data Pipeline.
The script works as expected when I run it directly using SQL Workbench/J, but fails when triggered through Data Pipeline.

I have reproduced the problem with this simple code:

```sql
drop table if exists image_stg;
create table image_stg (like image_full); 
select * from image_stg;
```

When I run it in Data Pipeline, I get this error:

> [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: relation "image_stg" does not exist;

I also got this error once, for the exact same code, without changing anything:

> [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: Relation with OID 108425 does not exist.;

Here's a screenshot of the two error messages:

[image: Sad screenshot]

I've found this thread on the AWS forums, but it didn't help: [Pipeline started failing on simple Redshift SqlActivity and temp table](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=678695)

What is causing this error? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Check your database connection in Data Pipeline, and try runnig the query with schema prefix (`drop table if exists <schema>.image_stg`

Comment: Does SQL workbench have autocommit on? Can you reproduce the problem by turning it off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've contacted Amazon, and it looks like a problem in Data Pipeline.
They did suggest a workaround that seems to work in my case:  Change the JDBC connection string from `jdbc:redshift://…` to `jdbc:postgresql://…` .

Comment: This solved my issue too, so I guess the bug is still there.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when creating a temporary table in Redshift via Pipeline but the workaround of changing the connection string from `jdbc:redshift://…` to `jdbc:postgresql://…` didn't work for me though. My last resort is to create the table as physical table and drop it after use - through Pipeline.

Comment: The table in my question isn't a `temp` table, but that didn't made any difference for me.